# catch all messages from Prism EventAggregator

Tags: c#, prism, eventaggregator

is there any option to catch all messages the event aggreator of Prism distributes? I may subscribe typed messages but I didn't find a way to listen to all messages.

Regards,
zimmy

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option. And I doubt there's a sensible use-case for this.

Comment: use cases: a) logging b) messages that implement an interface so that I can check this and reflect behavior on this: messages that implement interface A doing this, interface B doing that, not depending on a concrete message type.

Comment: That's what I meant by _sensible_... the event aggregator is a simple class to help decoupling view models, it's not akka.net :-)